# surf on two same size matrices in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am new to matlab and just learned about surf function. I have question. What is the meaning of surf when we use it on two same size matrices.

For example, in the following code :

```
A = [ 1 1 1 ; 2 2 2 ; 3 3 3] ;
B  = repmat(5,3,3);
surf(A,B)
surf(B,A)
```

The above two surf commands give different graphs. But what is the meaning of it?

Any explanation/resource would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you feed 2 inputs to `surf`, X and Y will be the sizes of the second and first dimensions of the arrays, respectively; Z (the height of the surface) will be the values of the first input, and the surface will be colored according to the values of the second input.

For behavior with other sets of inputs - at the command line, type `doc surf`.